# jquery minScrollBack: 'infinity' not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

The page still automatically scrolls to the last position even after applying the override.
I'm i not doing it correctly or what?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.datebox.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){ //jquery mobile override
    $.extend(  $.mobile , {
      minScrollBack:'infinity'

      });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do scroll to the first position?

Comment: im not scrolling anything or what.
when i navigate from page1(scroll down) --> page 2 --> page1
when i return to page 1 from page2 i don't want it to automatically return to my previous position.

Comment: have you tried 0? Not being proficient in jQuery Mobile i can't say for certain.

Comment: try adding `class="ui-title"` to something at the top of each your pages. Have you done this? Does it change the behavior?

Comment: If you look at the jsfiddle i posted in the answer it seems to work for that example. Maybe you have more code that is different from the example there. It might just be a start to work out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/puUan/1/

This jsfiddle shows how the `.ui-title` class set the focus to the top of the page.

```
<h1 class="ui-title">title page 1</h1>
```

should work. What happens is this: on page transition (or some such event) jQuery calls a function named `reFocus()` that looks like:

```
//direct focus to the page title, or otherwise first focusable element
function reFocus( page ) {
    var lastClicked = page.jqmData( "lastClicked" );

    if( lastClicked && lastClicked.length ) {
        lastClicked.focus();
    }
    else {
        var pageTitle = page.find( ".ui-title:eq(0)" );
        if( pageTitle.length ) {
           pageTitle.focus();
        }
        else{
            page.find( focusable ).eq( 0 ).focus();
        }
    }
}
```

the line: `page.find( focusable ).eq( 0 ).focus();` is probably focusing on a link you've clicked.

**Alternative:-**

comment out this call in `transistionPages(`

```
reFocus( toPage );
```

to:

```
//reFocus( toPage );
```

This will stop the function getting called altogether, (I personally don't see a reason for it.) but if you are using the jQuery Mobile from a CDN that probably not possible.